# Rewrite or Redirect URL in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

We have an internal site that we are changing to be publically viewable.

This is the old URL:

`http:\\help.internal.mysite.com`

and we want it to rewrite to:

`https:\\help.mysite.com`

So that links in emails will still work. An old URL is like this: `http:\\help.internal.mysite.com\article.php?1234`

A new site exists for the old url with a static page to show new url for internal users so going to the old page gives a 404 as it doesn't exist.

Will this be taken care of too?

Comment: Websites should use relative URL's to ensure when domains change they will be updated accordingly. Do you have any code samples to demonstrate where you believe you might be having problems?

Comment: Its URLs in emails that have been sent we are covering not the site itself. URLs within the site are relative and work fine. I'm struggling to understand RegExp as I haven't done it before and trying to use URL Rewrite in IIS

Comment: You can use the iis rewriting module for this. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have but I am not getting very far... I copy some rules but then when i add them the tests fail... very confusing!